Logback for specific class and file only
I want to use logback in Spring Boot application just for one specific class and to write to specific log file. I don't want logback to control my other app logging, because we have "out-of-the-box" log control.
This is my logback-spring.xml with custom appender:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <if condition='isDefined("log.directory")'>
        <then>
            <property name="LOG_LOCATION" value="${log.directory}" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="LOG_LOCATION" value="./custom-log" />
        </else>
    </if>


    <property name="CUSTOM_LOG" value="client-logs/custom-front"/>
    <appender name="CUSTOM_LOG_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_LOCATION}/${CUSTOM_LOG}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_LOCATION}/${CUSTOM_LOG}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="some.package.services.impl.ServiceImpl" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_LOG_APPENDER"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>

When app is starting logback expects logging.file.name property to be set, why? When I set logging file name it creates it but doesn't write to it. I don't want it to create or write to any .log file except that one I configured in logback.
Is there a way to define it?
